A problem about sum-closed permutations
Recently, I noted in this short note by M. Klazar the following problem.
A permutation $a_1a_2\ldots a_n$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, where $n$ is odd, is said to be a sum-closed permutation if $a_{2i}=a_{2i-1}+a_{2i+1}$ for $i=1,2, \ldots, (n-1)/2$. For instance, for $n=9$ the sum-closed permutations are
$$1\;4\;3\;9\;6\;8\;2\;7\;5\qquad   1\;5\;4\;7\;3\;9\;6\;8\;2 \qquad 5\;9\;4\;6\;2\;3\;1\;8\;7$$
$$5\;7\;2\;8\;6\;9\;3\;4\;1\qquad  2\;8\;6\;9\;3\;7\;4\;5\;1\qquad 7\;8\;1\;3\;2\;6\;4\;9\;5$$
Is it true that for any odd $n$ there is at least a sum-closed permutation?
The question has been posed in 1997. Is it still open? Any reference about this kind of up-down permutations?
